# How do I get the class of java.lang.Enum in scala?

Tags: java, scala, serialization, jackson

I am new to Scala and I am converting some Java code to Scala that uses the Jackson library to handle JSON serialization. I ran into a problem in a Jackson SimpleModule implementation.

In Java, I would do this:

```
 addSerializer(Enum.class, new LowerEnumSerializer());
```

I thought it would be as easy as doing this in Scala:

```
addSerializer(classOf[Enum], new LowerEnumSerializer())
```

However, my compiler is complaining:

> scala: class Enum takes type parameters addSerializer(classOf[Enum], new LowerEnumSerializer())

I am guessing that this is because Java's Enum looks like:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I can't use classOf[Enum[_]] because the addSerializer method looks like this:

```
public <T> SimpleModule addSerializer(Class<? extends T> type, JsonSerializer<T> ser)
```

**EDIT 2**
I can't use classOf[Enum[_ <: Enum[_]], I get:

```
Type mismatch, expected: JsonSerializer[_], actual: Class[Enum[_ <: Enum[_]]
```

JsonSerializer looks like:

```
public class LowerEnumSerializer extends StdScalarSerializer<Enum>
```

Comment: If you don't care about specific parameters, why don't you just say `classOf[Enum[_]]` which is analog to java's `Enum<?>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
classOf[Enum[T] forSome { type T <: Enum[T] }]
```